# Make a bot to automatically become a speaker in stage channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I was using `message.guild.me.voice.setRequestToSpeak(true);` to make a bot request to become a speaker in stage channel, but some bots can automatically become speakers if they have permissions in this stage channel. How can I make my bot become a speaker too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`VoiceState#setSuppressed()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=setSuppressed) to control whether your bot is a speaker or not in a stage channel.

```js
message.guild.me.voice.setSuppressed(false)
```

Comment: @MegaMix_Craft, what discord.js version are you running? Is the bot in a stage channel?